# Multivariate series inversion

Tags: multivariable-calculus, power-series, inverse

Is there any method for computation of the coefficients $A_i$, $B_i$, $u\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2],v\in[-\pi,\pi]$,  of the inverse series to

$$X=F(u,v)=a_1u^0v^1+a_2u^2v^1+a_3u^2v^3,$$
   $$Y=G(u,v)=b_1uv^0+b_2uv^2+b_3u^3v+b_4u^2v^3,$$

in the form of

$$u=A_1X^0Y^0+A_2X^0Y+A_3XY^0+A_4XY+...,$$
  $$v=B_1X^0Y^0+B_2X^0Y+B_3XY^0+B_4XY+B_5X^2Y+...,$$

or, only a numerical solution of the problem

$$min[(F(u,v)-X)^2 + (G(u,v)-Y)^2]$$

exists? For example, the Gauss-Newton method $h=-(J^TJ)^{-1}J^Tf$ may be used, where 
   $$J=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
     \partial F(u,v)/\partial u & \partial F(u,v)/\partial v\\
     \partial G(u,v)/\partial u & \partial G(u,v)/\partial v
   \end{array}\right].$$

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a univarite formal power series can be inverted
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x)&=&x+a_1 x^2+ a_2 x^3 +\cdots \\
f^{-1}(x) &=& x-a_1 x^2 +(2a_1^2 -a_2)x^3+ \cdots
\end{eqnarray*}
A $2$ dimensional analogue can be done in your case, let $a_1=1$ and $b_1=1$ for the sake of simplicity and this can be achieved by rescaling $u$ and $v$. Your function is $ T:(v,u) \rightarrow (X=F(u,v),Y=G(u,v))$
\begin{eqnarray*}
X&=&v+a_2 u^2 v + a_3 u^2 v^3 \\
Y&=&u +b_2 uv^2+b_3u^3v +b_4 u^2 v^3. 
\end{eqnarray*}
The inverse function $ T:(X,Y) \rightarrow (v=V(X,Y),u=U(X,Y))$ is (up to third order)
\begin{eqnarray*}
v=X-a_2 X Y^2 +\cdots \\
u= Y-b_2 X^2 Y +\cdots 
\end{eqnarray*}
Now add fourth order terms ( $\alpha_u X^4+ \beta_u X^3 Y + \gamma_u X^2 Y^2 +\delta_u X Y^3 +\epsilon_u Y^4$) to these series and use $ T \circ S (X,Y)=(X,Y)$ to calculate the next terms.

Comment: @ Donald: Thanks for your answer... Could I kindly ask you for a more detailed explanation of calculating all terms?

Comment: There is no easy general formula for the terms, but you can calculate them up to whatever order you bothered.

Comment: @ Donald: Not even up to order 3? The above-mentioned series represent a simplified example. Which method for finding $u$, $v$ could you recommend?